# Pointer to an object before sending message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I apologize if the title is somewhat misleading, I didn't know how to describe the problem. So I came across an online tutorial today and I encountered a line of code that got me asking a few questions.

For example this line of code

UIImageView *recipeImageView = **(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];** <--- What is this part?

What is it doing here? Does it return an instance of UIImageView(or converting it maybe)? I didn't know you could doing something like this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[cell viewWithTag:100]` is a method call (message send).  The pointer `cell` is the object pointer, and `viewWithTag` is the method of that object that is being called, passing as a parameter the numeric value 100.

The method call returns a UIView pointer which is cast into an UIImageView pointer (presumably because the programmer knows that's the correct type) before assigning to `recipeImageView`.

Comment: I mean this "(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];" right here. The UIImageView follows by a pointer?

Comment: `(UIImageView*)` is a "cast" -- a standard C construct that you should understand thoroughly before attempting to use Objective-C.

Comment: Alright thanks, it seems like I should read more about this. Will accept your answer as soon as they let me do it lol.